# How to view a user's personal data after the user performs a login?

Tags: users, database

I wonder how to view a user's personal data after the user performs a login.

Example: they have 4 tables in database "it", "business", "hrm", "educ". All the 4 tables have a student data when the 1st column in it table are login only the first column in table are viewed his data in webpage.

Answer (score 0):

You might be able to use the [Forena](https://www.drupal.org/project/forena) module (disclosure: I'm a co-maintainer) to build custom queries to retrieve the data directly from such **database** (of which its format can be MS SQL, MySql, Oracle, some PDO compliant database, etc). Think of those custom queries as standard SQL statements that fit your requirements (to retrieve the data). And combine this with the creation of some custom reports.

Those reports can then be shown in an appropriate page (with a specific path), or you could show them in a block, by using [Forena's integration with the BEAN module](http://drupal.placeto.be/reports/help.sitebuilding#bean).

PS: I'm assuming this question is about D7.